# Which subscription events to monitor for and which actions to take?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I have a subscription product that offers users monthly and annual subscriptions without free trials. All the docs I've seen kind of assume that I should know what types of actions to take when a new user subscribes to my service. The Stripe docs on [provision and monitor](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription#provision-and-monitor) say the minimum events to monitor are:

1. checkout.session.completed
2. invoice.paid
3. invoice.payment_failed

But then what do after monitoring for these events? In the [dj-stripe docs](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage/webhooks/) on webhooks there are some clues as to what I should be doing including:

- Notifying the customer via email
- "Invalidating a cache"
- "Fire off a celery task"

Is there anything else I should consider doing? And how do I know when to do what?

Sorry if these are newb questions but this all just seems really subjective and I am just grasping for some guidance. Of course with dj-stripe I will be adding a lot of info to the database and this is all handled automatically. And of know that I can and should email the user when an invoice is paid or payment failed.

But what about `checkout.session.completed`? Why is this a minimum event to monitor for? When a checkout session is completed Stripe redirects the user back to my site so what else should I do? Further, when testing Stripe locally with `stripe listen` when a checkout subscription is completed I see the below.

```
2022-01-03 10:43:13   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3KDtcoKxszORsacj2FQfXUML]
2022-01-03 10:43:13   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacjTw9deAqR]
2022-01-03 10:43:13   --> payment_method.attached [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacjaXyLietR]
2022-01-03 10:43:13   --> customer.created [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacj9uw5NaU8]
2022-01-03 10:43:13   --> customer.updated [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacjRinrFA0W]
2022-01-03 10:43:13   --> invoice.created [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacjrT6Iqq1d]
2022-01-03 10:43:13   --> invoice.finalized [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacjCEEjfN1A]
2022-01-03 10:43:13   --> customer.subscription.created [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacjJoc8bIwy]
2022-01-03 10:43:14   --> invoice.updated [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacjLWiDYTDN]
2022-01-03 10:43:14   --> customer.subscription.updated [evt_1KDtcrKxszORsacj8dw2DX35]
2022-01-03 10:43:14   --> invoice.paid [evt_1KDtcsKxszORsacjxJzrlZRS]
2022-01-03 10:43:14   --> invoice.payment_succeeded [evt_1KDtcsKxszORsacjzaBHyX6z]
2022-01-03 10:43:14   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3KDtcoKxszORsacj2XHeCjzp]
2022-01-03 10:43:14   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3KDtcoKxszORsacj29ByjaXa]
```

Are the only actionable events here the `invoice.paid` and `checkout.session.completed` ?
I may be overthinking this but I want to make sure I am doing this right and not letting anything fall through the cracks. Everything I have seen online seems to indicate I should "just know" which events to monitor for based on my business and "just know" what to do. If there is any more clarity that can be provided on what events to monitor for and what *needs* to be done I'd love to hear it. For reference, if legalese is involved, I am operating in the U.S. and kind of assuming GDPR. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `checkout.session.completed` event is only relevant if you're creating the subscription via Checkout -- it would not be emitted if you're creating subscriptions directly via the API.

The exact events that you need to listen to depend entirely on what you want to achieve! While subscribing to `invoice.payment_failed` is necessary to [handle failed payment recovery](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#payment-failures) yourself, you you might also choose to [allow Stripe to handle that](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#settings) for you with automatic recovery.

If you need to take some action in your system with each monthly renewal, then `invoice.paid` will be what you want for that, but isn't *necessary* in the strict sense.

Broadly, Stripe [recommends to only subscribe to events that you need](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-types) to run your business. None are strictly *required*, but some are commonly used.

If you can expand your question with the context of the actions you need/intend to take in your own system or with your customers, then I can try to recommend which events might be useful for that.

Comment: Thanks again, @Nolan! Do you have a moment that I can chat with you in a more synchronous manner on this? I am not sure if SO Chat is an option (I think if we go back and forth here enough they'll offer to move the convo to chat) or if something else is an option. I checked out your profile and I didn't see anything like codementor so let me know if you have any options like that please. Cheers!

Comment: (Also I am creating the subscription via Checkout.... the user is redirected back to my page but I never explicitly do anything with `checkout.session.completed`. The fact that the Stripe Checkout docs say this is a minimum event to handle and I'm doing nothing makes me a little concerned :-)

Comment: Hmm if not using the checkout event, what are you using for provisioning the new subscriptions? I assume `customer.subscription.created` which should provide the functionality you need, but would require you to link that subscription to the returning customer on your confirmation page using other information. Using the checkout event you'd be able to map that directly if you had no other customer info before the redirect, for example.

Comment: If you want to talk to folks synchronously about developer integration questions, you might try joining Stripe's developer community Discord: https://stripe.com/go/developer-chat